# Can i find an AngularJs plugin for eclipse?

Tags: angularjs, eclipse-plugin

Iam looking for an **AngularJs plugin for ECLIPSE**, did any one have an idea?

Thank you,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally haven't used it, but give this a try… https://github.com/sbegaudeau/AngularJS-Eclipse-Tools

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: You could look at [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse), but today it manages just HTML editor (syntax coloring, attributes name completions).